# Javascript sort numerically instead of alphabetically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to sort rows alphabetically and it works pretty good, but if it contains numbers it will sort it a1, a10, a11, ..., a2, a20, ..., a3 instead of a1, a2, a3 etc.

```
function sort(element) {
 var sortableList = element;
 var listitems = $('tr', sortableList);

 listitems.sort(function (a, b) {

     return ($(a).find('td.myclass').text().toUpperCase() > $(b).find('td.myclass').text().toUpperCase()) ? 1 : -1;
 });
 sortableList.append(listitems);

}
```

Trying with this code form the example below. Not working yet:

```
function sort(element) {
 var sortableList = element;
 var listitems = $('tr', sortableList);
 var word = /[a-z]/i,
    digit = /\d+/;

listitems.sort(function (a, b) {
   return +$(a).find('td.myclass').text().match(digit)[0] > +$(b).find('td.myclass').text().match(digit)[0] ? 1 : -1;
}).sort(function (a, b) {
   return $(a).find('td.myclass').text().match(word)[0] > $(b).find('td.myclass').text().match(word)[0] ? 1 : -1;
});
 sortableList.append(listitems);

}
```

Error: `null is not an object (evaluating '$(b).find('td.myclass').text().match(digit)[0]')`

Comment: Can you post a failing example of your use case. As long as all  the elements in `listitems` are all strings or numbers it should not be a problem.

Comment: @Xufox `"80" > "9"` and `80 > 9` will give you the same results. As long as `a` and `b` are of the same primitive type, should not be a problem. The issue arises only if one is a number and another is a string.

Comment: I updated my post. It has to work on mixed characters, not only int.

Comment: @Sushanth-- _“`"80" > "9"` and `80 > 9` will give you the same results.”_ — this is false.

Comment: @Xufox My bad. You are right.

Comment: What result do you want to have of you'll try to compare a1 and 1?

Comment: 1 should be first. Just like on a mac (or probably pc too) if you have files and folders they will sort that way. 1, 2, 2a, 3, a1, a2, a10

Comment: do you want them ordered by rows or all the columns ordered in general?

Comment: @SeaBass Can you include HTML and expected result at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @quirimmo rows, based on the string in the first column

Comment: Chain `.match()` to `.text()` call, e.g., `+$(a).find('td.myclass').text()`, `$(a).find('td.myclass').match(word)[0]`, `.match()` is [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), which expected to the chained to a string, which `$.fn.text()` returns, though `.match()` is still not a jQuery method

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks! Updated the post again with the error at the bottom.

Comment: I guess I need to figure out how I can replace the match() with jquery equivalent?

Comment: The error indicates that no match was found within the `.textContent` of the element. Can you include HTML at Question, reproduce the error at stacksnippets? Use of or no use of jQuery is not the issue.

Comment: @guest271314 Something like this `<table><tr><td>a1</td></tr><tr><td>a2</td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td>a10</td></tr></table>`

Comment: or that one of your elements has no numeric part in the text

Comment: It should work for empty cell, numeric cell, alphabetical cell, mixed cell.

Comment: well, that's not what you say in the question at all

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry about that. Maybe it just needs to be tweaked so it still runs even if it doesn't contain a value. I assume that's why I get the null error.

Comment: `<tr>` is not a valid child element of a `<tr>` element

Comment: @guest271314 I know. If this is easier. Ignore my code. How can I use your code to sort a table with rows based on the text vale in the first cell of each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work as expected, regardless of complexity of text ...

```js
function sort(sortableList) {
    $(sortableList).append([].slice.call($('tr', sortableList)).map(function (e) {
        return { element: e, values: ($(e).find('td').text().toUpperCase() || '').match(/([A-Z]+|\d+)/g) };
    }).sort(function (aa, bb) {
        var valuesA = aa.values ||[];
        var valuesB = bb.values ||[];
        var len = Math.min(valuesA.length, valuesB.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var a = valuesA[i];
            var b = valuesB[i];
            if (a === b) {
                continue;
            }
            var aIsNum = !isNaN(parseInt(a));
            var bIsNum = !isNaN(parseInt(b));
            if (aIsNum && bIsNum) {
                return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
            }
            if (!(aIsNum && bIsNum)) {
                return a > b ? 1 : -1;
            }
            if (aIsNum) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 1;
        }
        return valuesA.length - valuesB.length;
    }).map(function (e) {
        return e.element;
    }));
    document.getElementById('msg').textContent = 'Sorted';
}
setTimeout(function () {
    return sort(document.querySelector('table'));
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="msg">Wait for it ....</span>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background:red"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! I get this: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '...'. Expected a property name.`

Comment: oh dear @SeaBass - are you using a microsoft browser? - let me "transpile" that for you

Comment: hehe latest Safari. Maybe there's some other stuff in my code that screw it up.

Comment: @SeaBass - try now, if that doesn't work, I'll post pre 2015 javascript

Comment: @SeaBass - see if that vanilla pre 2015 version of code works - looks damn ugly now

Comment: @JaromandaX Works, thank you! But man this was harder than I thought! I just want it to sort like in a normal folder on the computer. If you enter 1a1, 1a10, 1a2 in your example it wont sort 1a1, 1a2, 1a10 right?

Comment: well, no, you'll need a more complex algorithm ... however

Comment: @JaromandaX Ok. Thank you for all your help. I just didn't know that it was so complicated and made a disservice by simplifying my question. In MySQL I think I can just choose the sorting type and boom. Was expecting something similar. Again, my apologies.

Comment: I've updated the answer - it's amazing, your "more complex" question made the answer easier :p

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
"use strict";

let myArr = ['a1', 'c', 'c56','a', 'ac2', 'ab21', 1, '5a', 6, 'A16', 'b', 3, 'a3', 'abc'];
let result = [];

function compareNumeric(a, b) {
    return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
}

function compareStr(a, b) {
    return a.toUpperCase() > b.toUpperCase();
}

function compareStrNum(a, b) {
    if (a.match(/[a-z]+/i)[0].toUpperCase() === b.match(/[a-z]+/i)[0].toUpperCase()) {
        if (a.match(/\d+/) === null) {
            return 0;
        }

        return +a.match(/\d+/)[0] - +b.match(/\d+/)[0];
    }
}

function compare(arr) {
    let numeric = [];
    let str = [];

    for (let i = 0, max = arr.length; i < max; i++) {

        if (parseInt(arr[i])) {
            numeric.push(arr[i]);
        } else {
            str.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    numeric = numeric.sort(compareNumeric);
    str.sort(compareStr)
        .sort(compareStrNum);

    result = result.concat(numeric);
    result = result.concat(str);
}

compare(myArr);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, I see it working in your code with an array, but I don't know how to make it work with my code in the original post.

Comment: can you provide me with more information which data to you want to compare? You can add html code as an example

Comment: My whole function is in my original post. I have a table with cells and want them to be ordered the way described.

Comment: Or lets put it this way. Ignore my code. How can I apply this method to sort a table with rows based on the text vale in the first cell of each row?

Comment: Updated! Function ' compare' returns value 1 / -1 for sorting

just use argument a, b for compare function in array mode

Comment: Thank you! One last thing. How do I get the `.find('td.myclass')` part in there?

Comment: just put them in arguments

Comment: something like this listitems.sort(compare ([$(a).find('td.myclass').text(), $(b).find('td.myclass').text()]));